# sorting values in an object via its values - js

Tags: javascript

In order to better understand how to manipulate objects, I'm trying to sort an object based on its values.

eg.

```
let obj = {
    1: 5,
    2: 4,
    3: 200,
    4: 3,
    5: 1
}
```

and I want an output of

```
{
    3: 200,
    1: 5,
    2: 4,
    4: 3,
    5: 1
}
```

I've looped through the object and added its key value pairs into a new array, which I then sort by the values.

the new array looks like this

```
[
    [3, 200],
    [1, 5],
    [2, 4],
    [4, 3],
    [5, 1]
]
```

I then loop through this array and create a new object from it, but it's coming out as

```
{ 1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 200, 4: 3, 5: 1 }
```

why?

```js
let obj = {
  1: 5,
  2: 4,
  3: 200,
  4: 3,
  5: 1
}

const sortObj = o => {
  const arr = [];
  const _obj = {};

  for (const v in o) arr.push([v, o[v]]);

  arr.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

  for (const v of arr) {
    console.log(v);
    /*
    [
      [3, 200],
      [1, 5],
      [2, 4],
      [4, 3],
      [5, 1]
    ]
    */
    const [key, val] = v;
    console.log(key, val);
    _obj[key] = val;
  }

  return _obj;
}

console.log(sortObj(obj));
```

Comment: That isn’t possible with objects. Properties don’t have a reliable order.

Comment: You can never guarantee the order of properties when printing an `object`. Object properties just don't have order. You have to use array when you need order.

Comment: "Sorting an object" makes no sense: you can create an array with key/value pairs and sort that: objects are unordered.

Comment: I partially disagree with the previous comments. In modern browsers and ES spec, the order of objects is almost always preserved. One of the few times they're not, however, is when the keys are integers.

Comment: If you're using ES6, you can use `Map`, it respects insertion order

Comment: but why does this work if the keys were strings rather than integers?

Comment: It doesnt work with strings either

Comment: @RainerPlumer I posted an answer below with OP's exact code, replaced with strings, and it works. May I ask which browser you're using, or better yet, which order you see the output in?

Comment: @RainerPlumer http://jsfiddle.net/gw9sna3q/

Comment: As integer keys behave "similar" to array index (`var a = {1:"a"}` the property `1` is accessed by `a[1]`) so they are usually printed in order, I guess.

Comment: @JohanP http://jsfiddle.net/b5wnq7kx/ does the same with map

Comment: @totalnoob You need to use `Map.set(key, value)` not the way you're doing it

Answer (score 1):

As of ES2015, your objects keys will *almost* always preserve their order of insertion. However, one of the few notable exceptions is when your *keys are integers*.

The example below shows that the sort works fine when we use `string` keys instead...

```js
let obj = {
  test: 5,
  this: 4,
  out: 200,
  and: 3,
  see: 1
}

const sortObj = o => {
  const arr = [];
  const _obj = {};

  for (const v in o) arr.push([v, o[v]]);

  arr.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

  for (const v of arr) {
    const [key, val] = v;
    _obj[key] = val;
  }

  return _obj;
}

console.log(sortObj(obj));
```

Alternatively, use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead, which **always** preserves order.

```js
let obj = {
  1: 5,
  2: 4,
  3: 200,
  4: 3,
  5: 1
}

const sortObj = o => {
  const arr = [];
  const _obj = new Map();

  for (const v in o) arr.push([v, o[v]]);

  arr.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

  for (const v of arr) {
    const [key, val] = v;
    _obj.set(key, val);
  }

  return _obj;
}

var sortedMap = sortObj(obj);
sortedMap.forEach((val, key) => console.log(`${key}: ${val}`));
```

Comment: Symbols are also treated differently. IMO it makes zero sense to rely on insertion order across arbitrary keys: treat an object as it was originally intended, an unordered collection of key/values. If you need order, enforce it in other ways. E.g., http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html

Comment: @DaveNewton Correct - and I agree! I'd provided the alternative solution of using `Map` for this reason. The first point stands to explain the "Why is this not working", whereas hopefully the second part tackles the "What should I be doing instead?".

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is already a valid answer above but ill post it since i already started to play around with the ordering and have a bit shorter version.

Related reading:
[Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

```
let obj = {
    1: 5,
    2: 4,
    3: 200,
    4: 3,
    5: 1
}
sortedObj = Object.keys(obj).sort((key1, key2) => {
    if (obj[key1] > obj[key2]) {return -1;}
    if (obj[key1] < obj[key2]) {return 1;}
    return 0;
}).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc['i_'+key] = obj[key];
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map` if you can, it'll preserve order as mentioned in my comment above. The bonus of using `Map`, your keys won't get converted to strings, it preserves the type too.

```js
let obj = {
  1: 5,
  2: 4,
  3: 200,
  4: 3,
  5: 1
}

const sortObj = o => {
  const arr = [];
  const map = new Map();

  for (const v in o) arr.push([v, o[v]]);

  arr.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

  for (const v of arr) {
    console.log(v);
    /*
    [
      [3, 200],
      [1, 5],
      [2, 4],
      [4, 3],
      [5, 1]
    ]
    */
    const [key, val] = v;
    //console.log(key, val);
    map.set(key,val);
  }

  return map;
}
sortObj(obj).forEach((k,v)=>console.log(v,k))
```

Comment: While you're correct that `Map` preserves type, the keys will turn to string values in this example. If you do `var obj = { ... }; console.log(obj)`, you'll see that the keys have already been converted to strings, therefore they're added to the `Map` as strings :)